# One-to-Many Navigation Property seems to work for Post but not for get

Tags: c#, entity-framework-core, one-to-many

I'm new to Entity Framework, and I'm trying to create a pair of entity classes that have a one-to-many relationship. The tutorials and articles I've found just tell you how to set up the two classes. I followed their instructions and have verified that the child objects do automatically set the foreign key to the parent key's value, which is right, and SaveChanges on the context works (or does not give an error). But when I do a get, the collection is null.

I think I'm missing something I need to do that the tutorials and articles take for granted. Do I need to do something in my get to ensure that the ICollection in my parent class gets filled?

Here's the Parent entity:

```
public class Character 
{
    [Key]
    public string Id { get; private set; }
    ...

    public virtual ICollection<Fault> Faults { get; set; }
}
```

And Here's my child:

```
public class Fault
{
    [Key]
    [DatabaseGenerated( DatabaseGeneratedOption.Identity )]
    public string FaultId { get; set; }
    public string FaultName { get; set; }

    public string CharacterId { get; set; }
    public virtual Character Character { get; set; }
}
```

In my context, I added:

```
public DbSet<Character> Characters { get; set; }
public DbSet<Fault> Faults { get; set; }
```

Is there anything else I need to do? The Post seems to succeed, but the get of Character doesn't give me a filled in collection for Faults. Do I have to manually query the Faults and build the collection?

Comment: [Loading Related Data](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/ef/core/querying/related-data/)

Comment: Can you show the code where you got the error. pls?

Comment: A) show the relevant code ([mcve]). B) what Igor says.

Comment: A POST can be used at client to send a request to a server or a a server sending a response to the client.  GET can be used to capture the request at server or 
 to capture the response at client.  Controller has a serialize method to take the classes and converts to a byte array to send and a deserialize method to take the receive bytes and create a class object.   Not clear where you are looking at the receive data.  A normal response has a 200 OK status.Bad response will have a 400/500 error status and not body so the deserialize will fail.  The Post is the body of the request/response.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you say that the create works and you see it saved it your data file

Then when querying to get the data you need to include it

```
dataSource.Character.Include(x => x.Faults )
```

See this link https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.data.entity.infrastructure.dbquery-1.include?view=entity-framework-6.2.0

Comment: This was it! I knew there was something the docs I read was leaving out. And it makes sense. Thanks for the quick response and the great help.